# Custom post type and hierarchical taxonomy permalinks

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I've seen this asked all over the internet, but so far nothing has worked for me.

Ideally, I'd like the following to work:

`http://example.com/mortgage-brokers` < taxonomy archive

`http://example.com/mortgage-brokers/victoria` < taxonomy term

`http://example.com/mortgage-brokers/victoria/melbourne` < second-level taxonomy term

`http://example.com/mortgage-brokers/victoria/melbourne/john-smith` < single 'post'

I have the 'Custom post type permalinks' plugin set to `/%broker_locations%/%postname%/`, and I've defined my CPT & taxonomy as follows:

```
    $args = array(  
        'label' => __('Brokers'),  
        'singular_label' => __('Broker'),  
        'public' => true,  
        'show_ui' => true,  
        'capability_type' => 'post',  
        'hierarchical' => false,  
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => [
            'hierarchical' => false,  
            'slug' => 'mortgage-brokers',
            'with_front' => false
        ],  
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'tag', 'comments'),
       );  

    register_post_type( 'broker' , $args );  


    register_taxonomy(  
        'broker_locations',
        'broker',
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => true,  
            'label' => 'Broker locations',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'with_front' => false
            )
        )  
    );
```

With the above configuration I can get post permalinks to work, as long I don't add a slug to 'rewrite' in the taxonomy definition, resulting in 'broker_locations' in the slug, i.e:

`http://example.com/mortgage-brokers/victoria/melbourne/john-smith` < works

`http://example.com/mortgage-brokers/victoria/melbourne` < 404s

`http://example.com/mortgage-brokers/broker_locations/victoria/melbourne` < "works", but isn't desired

I've also been able to get either nested taxonomy archives OR post permalinks to work fine (depending on which one's defined first in functions.php), but the other one always 404s.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I can't believe how difficult something so simple has been.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's stumbling across this, I've found my answer:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196797/add-taxonomy-in-custom-permalink-structure/196799

'AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd' in that thread has written their own function that'll fix this. It's somewhat manual in that you have to specify how many levels deep your post is, but it certainly did the trick for me.

Comment: You should be able to comment on your own posts, even if you don'y have enough rep for comments generally. Link-only answers are discouraged so this could get removed, so I'd suggest either adding a comment, or update this answer with a summary of what helped you from that link -  See [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Ah, noted. Thanks for that!